# Extension zero of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\omega$ compactly contained in $\Omega$. Suppose $u \in W^{k,p}(\omega)$ and supp $u$ compactly contained in $\Omega$.

I want to ask about the zero extension of $u$ on $\Omega$. Is it actually in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Extension_operators). And I think it is enough to ask if $v \in C^k(\omega)$ can be extended boundedly  (and $C^k$) to a slightly larger open.